# How to record NovAtel Raw Observation data in binary for post-processing

Tags: ros, bagfile, binary, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

New here, is there a way to record raw binary data to a bagfile without using a ROS standard message?  I would like to post-process using RTKLIB.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275121/how-to-record-novatel-raw-observation-data-in-binary-for-post-processing/) by [damascus_west](https://answers.ros.org/users/32513/damascus_west/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-07**:
Are you using any ROS drivers for interfacing with the receiver? If so, please mention those, as there are a nr of different components, which probably all do things slightly differently.

**Comment by [damascus_west](https://answers.ros.org/users/32513/damascus_west/) on 2017-11-07**:
I am using a ROS driver.  Here is the link: https://github.com/GAVLab/novatel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't have to be a *standard* message, but `rosbag` works with messages, so anything in there will have to be some message type.

---

Edit:

> I am using a ROS driver.  Here is the link: https://github.com/GAVLab/novatel.

That driver seems to only publish `NavSatFix` and `Odometry` messages.

You could perhaps take a look at [novatel_span_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/novatel_span_driver). Provided it is compatible with your hardware, that would seem to publish a lot of low-level data: see the [novatel_msgs](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/novatel_msgs/html/index-msg.html) docs.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damascus_west](https://answers.ros.org/users/32513/damascus_west/) on 2017-11-07**:
Thank you, I think I have a solution.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-07**:
Would be nice if you could tell us what solution you've come up with. That would benefit future visitors of this board.

**Comment by [damascus_west](https://answers.ros.org/users/32513/damascus_west/) on 2017-11-07**:
Certainly, I will see if I can make this work.